# Visitors who visited article X also visited article Y (Google Analytics)

Tags: google-analytics, recommendation-engine

I want to build a simple recommender system for my wiki site. How can I get  'visitors who read article X also read article Y' (where 'read article' = 'visit page') in Google Analytics?

I'm quite new to GA and I've tried experimenting with Advanced Segmentation but I can't seem to figure it out. Maybe I would need the Google Analytics API for this?

Huge thanks to anyone who can help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a couple different ways.

1 - Use Sequential Segments

[image]

2 - If you want to pull data out of the API you can use `ga:previousPagePath` or `ga:nextPagePath` dimensions to see what articles they viewed.

3 - you can also set session level [custom dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/customdimsmets) on a certain articles and then view what other articles they visited.